# Does anyone have a description of the return codes from libusb on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb

I am trying to debug a libusb-based driver that work just fine on Linux and Windows, but fail on Mac OS X. However I am unable to find a description of the return codes from libusb.

Comment: I've already read http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__misc.html, but I get error code -60 which is not in that list. I am also using the compat API if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's documentation and brief descriptions [here](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__misc.html) - are these the codes you mean?

```
enum libusb_error {
    LIBUSB_SUCCESS = 0,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_IO = -1,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM = -2,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS = -3,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE = -4,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND = -5,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY = -6,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT = -7,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW = -8,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE = -9,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_INTERRUPTED = -10,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_MEM = -11,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED = -12,
    LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER = -99
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find these codes [here](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__misc.html).

[This might](http://osdir.com/ml/lib.libusb.devel.general/2008-03/msg00016.html) be of interest for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the last link! From errno.h I find that it -60 means that the operation times out. Now I just have to figure out why.

Comment: let me know what you found out